# iMac Airport card faulty?

Tags: network, wifi

Is there any way of checking if the Airport card on my 2011 iMac has had it? It was working ok but intermittently dropping out and saying it couldn't reconnect to the network and now it is not seeing any network at all anymore.

Other machines connect to the network ok. Rebooting off a newly installed system on another partition doesn't fix it either.

Comment: you'd probably have to put it in another Mac, or depending on what, exactly, the card is (PCIe, PCMCIA, etc.) **any** other computer that it will fit in.

Comment: Have you recently changed your Wifi router (or whatever provides your wifi)? Does Ethernet work? What does System Information (option-click on Apple at top left) show under Network - WiFi? But from your description "working > intermittent dropouts > not connecting > not seeing any network" (and not working on new install) sounds like it is now dead :(

Comment: many thanks! i haven't changed anything with router or wifi but i will check if ethernet works.